# filtering array elements from string columns bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have two tables

first table

```
Row  feature_groups           array_words   
1    chat seller              chat
2    product picture/video    product picture
                              video
```

second table

```
Row  events                                       
1    product picture is perfect     
2    video on product babyboy
3    chat bot creation
4    image gorilla
```

**I want to filter out the events on the basis of array_words**

Result should be -

```
Row  events                         feature_groups
1    product picture is perfect     product picture/video
2    video on product babyboy       product picture/video
3    chat bot creation              chat seller
```

Any help with biqquery can be of great help

Comment: how do you pretend to join both tables? do you have any ID that matches both?

Comment: I can do cross join, no matching id column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select events, feature_groups from (
  select *, 
    (
      select count(1)
      from unnest(split(t2.events, ' ')) word
      join t1.array_words word
      using(word)
    ) match
  from table_2 t2, table_1 t1
  where true
  qualify row_number() over(partition by events order by match desc) = 1
  and match > 0
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question

Table_1
[image]

and Table_2
[image]

output is

[image]

Comment: thanks , that solves it